# how to unset all multidimensional arrays with some exception keys

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [zero] => 0
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
)
```

I made several keys for exceptions that would be unset (zero and two).
I also got this code in another sources but it doesn't apply if I add a symbol !

```
$r = ["zero" => 0, "one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3];
$dontRemove = array('zero','two');
$r = array_diff_key($r, array_flip($dontRemove));
```

result is

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [three] => 3
)
```

result i want is to unset keys one and three, like this

```
Array
(
    [zero] => 0
    [two] => 2
)
```

Comment: show us your expected outcome, that might help to clarify what it is you're trying to achieve exactly

Comment: okey updeted ...

Comment: @ogebman To get a difference, you use `array_diff_key`. To get something common, you use `array_intersect_key`. So, just use `array_intersect_key` instead of  `array_diff_key`.

Comment: @ogebman  mark the answer which worked for you so that question got close for further answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$r = ["zero" => 0, "one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3];
$dontRemove = array($r['zero'],$r['two']);
$r = array_intersect($r, $dontRemove);
print_r($r);
```

> Array
>   (
>       [zero] => 0
>       [two] => 2
>   )

I think you can solve it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `array_filter`:

```
$r = ["zero" => 0, "one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3];
$dontRemove = array('zero','two');
print_r(array_filter(
    $r, 
    function($k) use ($dontRemove) { return in_array($k, $dontRemove); },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
));
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another option, not using function(s) - `$result` contains the desired outcome:

```
$filter = ['zero', 'two'];
foreach($array as $akey => $aval) {
    foreach($filter as $fkey => $fval) {
        if($akey === $fval) $result[$akey] = $aval;
    }
}
```